# Joining Multiple Rows in a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Table_One:

```
+---------+----------+
|  USER_ID|   name   |
+---------+----------+
|    2    |   Rick   |
+---------+----------+
```

Table_Two

```
+---------+----------+----------+
|  t2_ID  |  sport   |  USER_ID |
+---------+----------+----------+
|    32   | football |     2    |
+---------+----------+----------+
|    33   | baseball |     2    |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

The result I am hoping for is the following:

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+
|    2    |  Rick    | Football, Baseball |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

I don't understand how to combined multiple rows from an INNER JOIN into one column like this.

```
SELECT Table_One.* FROM Table_One LEFT JOIN Table_Two ON Table_Two.USER_ID = Table_One.USER_ID
```

I am getting results as separate rows:

```
+---------+----------+----------+
|    2    |  Rick    | football |
+---------+----------+----------+
|    2    |  Rick    | baseball |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Thank you everyone who read this.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using ?

Comment: This goes against the principles of structured data tables, if you have to do it you can use `string_agg()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Using Sequal Pro

Comment: @user8834780 That's why I asked for the version, it's available only on 2017+

Comment: good point, if it is before 2017- see @Yogesh Sharma's answer below

Comment: nice i didn't know you could do that with string_agg(), when that was not available, i used to pivot and concat values.

Comment: Sequal Pro is for MySQL.  You've tagged this as SQL-Server.  Please correct your post.

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWERS THE QUESTION BASED ON TAG BEFORE ANY COMMENT/EDIT MADE.

You can use `FOR XML PATH()` clause :

```
SELECT to.*,
       STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' +tt.sport   
               FROM Table_Two tt
               WHERE tt.USER_ID = to.USER_ID
               FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
           ) AS Sports
FROM Table_One to;
```

Comment: I was mistaken it is MySQL 5.6.27  Should this still work? I', getting an error near "XML_PATH

Comment: @RON2015. . . Then look @ `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think I got it!